# Extending interface with GetHashCode method for use as key in generic dictionary (C#)

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, interface, extension-methods

In C#, is it possible to extend interfaces with GetHashCode and Equals in order to override default behavior when using interfaces as the key type in generic dictionaries?

```
public interface IFoo {
    int MagicNumber { get; }
}

public static class IFooExtensions {
    public static int GetHashCode(this IFoo foo) { return foo.MagicNumber; }
    public static bool Equals(this IFoo foo, object other) { 
        return foo.MagicNumber == other.GetHashCode(); 
    }
}

public class Foo : IFoo {
    public MagicNumber { get; set; }
    public Foo(int number) { MagicNumber = number; }
}

Dictionary<IFoo, string> dict = new Dictionary<IFoo, string>();
Foo bar = new Foo(7);
dict[bar] = "Win!"
```

In this toy example, will Foo objects used as keys in the dictionary use the interface extension methods or the object methods?

Comment: BTW, `return foo.MagicNumber == other.GetHashCode();` you can get away with that for `int` because `int` returns itself as the hashcode, but any other type would likely get you false positive matches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both a extension method and a class/interface define a method and they are exactly the same method signature the compiler will always choose the version that is on the class over the extension method.

You would be much better off just writing a `IEqualityComparer<IFoo>` then doing `new Dictionary<IFoo, string>(new MyFooComparer())` when you create the dictionary.

Comment: You imply it but I'd add that since `object` defines `GetHashCode` there is no way to get the dictionary to use an "extension" version.

Comment: @DStanley yes, I should have been more clear. I will also add and even if it was not `object` that defined it and instead was some other class it would still be "on the class" and choose the class version over the extension method.